# Bootstrap, CSS layout design fixing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've got a design of the section as displayed below,
[image]
**I need to create the same using bootstrap/CSS, Here's what I tried so far**

```css
.content-test-section {
    padding: 10px;
}
h3.section-head-number {
    color: #5fa936;
}
.vertical-line {
    border-left: 5px solid black;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="row content-test-section">
    <div class="col-lg-6 block-div">
      <h3 class="section-head-number">01</h3>
      <div class="vertical-line">
        <h4>Create Account</h4>
        <p>Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 block-div">
      <h3 class="section-head-number">02</h3>
      <div class="vertical-line">
        <h4>Create Account</h4>
        <p>Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is quite time consuming for me and I need to finish it asap.
I'd really appreciate if someone could help me out with it.

Comment: so what you want now,that blur or font or what you want

Comment: I've blurred the font for some other reason. I definitely need the font similarly as the snippet added above but the layout is what I need help with

Comment: you mean the zig-zag layout right?

Comment: yes @Neptotech-vishnu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.content-test-section {
    padding: 10px;
}
h3.section-head-number {
    color: #5fa936;
}
.vertical-line {
    border-left: 5px solid black;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
.mt-70px{
 margin-top:70px;
}
.d-flex{
  display:flex;
}
.mt-5{
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="d-flex flex-row">
    <div class="flex-column">
    <div class="col-lg-7 block-div">
      <h3 class="section-head-number">01</h3>
      <div class="vertical-line">
        <h4>Create Account</h4>
        <p>Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7 block-div mt-5">
      <h3 class="section-head-number">03</h3>
      <div class="vertical-line">
        <h4>Create Account</h4>
        <p>Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data</p>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 block-div mt-5">
      <h3 class="section-head-number">05</h3>
      <div class="vertical-line">
        <h4>Create Account</h4>
        <p>Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
     <div class="flex-column">
      <div class="col-lg-7 block-div mt-70px">
      <h3 class="section-head-number">02</h3>
      <div class="vertical-line">
        <h4>Create Account</h4>
        <p>Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data</p>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 block-div mt-70px">
      <h3 class="section-head-number">04</h3>
      <div class="vertical-line">
        <h4>Create Account</h4>
        <p>Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data</p>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 block-div mt-70px">
      <h3 class="section-head-number">06</h3>
      <div class="vertical-line">
        <h4>Create Account</h4>
        <p>Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data Dummy Data</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohit, well fortunately I finished the design already but definitely your answer helped me understand why my snippet wasn't working as expected